# What happens to the data when a docker container crashes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, docker

We are trying to move onto Docker for deployment purpose. Our architecture requires to have a redis, a mongodb and several nodejs and java based Docker containers.

So my question is, **if suppose the redis/mongodb docker container crashes, do we loose all the data that it had?**

***We want isolation, but at the same time we don't want to loose data*** due to malfunction/crashes. Is this even possible to achieve this with Docker or is it something not relevant here?

Any help or comments will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The answer is: YES - If a container crashes so that it can not be restored/restarted the data is gone. But, normally containers can be restarted and continued - in that case the data is not lost.

E.g. - the following sequence from the docker docs illustrates how container startup work. Note that the data is not lost here until the container is removed.

```
# Start a new container
$ JOB=$(sudo docker run -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo Hello world; sleep 1; done")

# Stop the container
$ sudo docker stop $JOB

# Start the container
$ sudo docker start $JOB

# Restart the container
$ sudo docker restart $JOB

# SIGKILL a container
$ sudo docker kill $JOB

# Remove a container
$ sudo docker stop $JOB # Container must be stopped to remove it
$ sudo docker rm $JOB
```

Whenever you execute a `docker run` command you start a new container with fresh data. The data is based on the image you provide and that data is consistent (unless you rebuild the image of course).

So, how should you setup docker to keep your data intact? I think that a good approach is to keep the important data mounted in a `volume`. Volumes are simply external folders (i.e. a folder from the host system) that holds the data and this data will not be lost even if you reinstall the entire docker daemon.

Example:

```
docker run -v /some/local/dir:/some/dir/in/redis-container my/redis
```

This mounts the host folder `/some/local/dir` as the folder `/some/dir/in/redis-container` in the running container. If e.g. `redis` stores its data in that folder you're all set to go and reboots/crashes can be survived.

More info about docker volumes check out the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems). Another great article is the also from the docker website, [Managing Data in Containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

**EDIT:** After comments I clarified the answer - the data is lost if the container can't be restarted (total crash).

Comment: Thanks @wassgren
I was suspecting this. But I am wondering will there be any significant performance penalties if I use volumes?
I am not sure how that works. Does the Kernel passes the information to the host Kernel which then saves the data. If so, will it be an efficient solution?

Comment: Volumes are faster than the layered filesystem used by Docker containers.  However note that the first sentence of this answer is wrong; try restarting it as mbarthelemy says.

Comment: @Bryan, thanks for the input! I considered a *crash* as non-recoverable. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Not exactly you can still either do docker cp or go find your files on Docker's layers

Answer (score 6):

If a container crashes, you **won't** lose any data - at least not more than with a regular application crash.

The container itself is unlikely to crash (after all, it's only an envelope for your application(s)). Your application(s) running in a container can crash, and if they do, their **data will still be on the container filesystem**. All you have to do in such a situation is to restart the failed container.

One case where you could lose something is if you explicitly tell Docker to remove the container when it's not running anymore (`--rm` option).

That being said, for IO-intensive applications such as databases, it is highly recommended to host data on Docker *volumes*, for performance reasons (a docker *volume* is a traditional filesystem, while the container default filesystem is a stack of layers and will be slower).

Comment: Thanks @mbarthelemy
I will have a look into docker volume.

Comment: By the way as @wassgren said, you will loose data if the container crashes, but not if you use volumes. Hope I am correct.